# How to separately send email to the form

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait, selenium4

I made web contact form, my email sending to subscribe email box , I want to send email to the form only. Please help me

```py
driver.get('https://shop.rtrpilates.com/')
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Contact'),click
```

```py
try:
    username_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]')
    username_box.send_keys("n@gmail.com")
```

I don't understand how can I create a block between this, Help please
Advance thanks

Comment: What is about your previous question? have you tried the given there answer?

Comment: @Prophet Hey, I want send email to the form only, but once I open web page then email is sending to the subscribe email area. 
How can I create a block where email only send to the contact form

Comment: Got it. Will try to help shortly

Comment: @Prophet thanks grateful to you, Waiting for you

Comment: Yes, My previous problem is solved. grateful to you
Now I stuck with this problem, I cannot create a block to stop send email to the subscribe  area before opening contact page form..
@Prophet

Comment: @Prophet hey it's working for that website , But it's not working for another website 

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Contact')
???
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]').click()

I want send email command based on clicking contact url link. If there is no contact link then email command will pass.

Comment: First of all the rule is: you can not create general Selenium code that will work on all web sites since each site has it own structure for each web page. Even if there are several sites having `Contact` or `Contact Us` text on some menu button in most cases the code worked on site A will not work on site B.

Comment: Similarly to: if you have frontend code for some page / element of some web site - you will still have to **create** a new code for another site. **maybe** some details will be similar, but still you can not copy-paste nothing from one site to another.

Comment: Also, this question is resolved and should be indicated as resolved. In case you have more questions - please open new questions for that.

Comment: You are welcome, Udi's father :)

Comment: @Prophet  can you please check my new question? prophet

Comment: I see no new questions from you

Comment: @Prophet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74675138/how-to-get-user-whose-dms-is-open-using-twitter-api?noredirect=1#comment131803555_74675138

Comment: I never used twitter API, so I don't know, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you main problem here is that you trying to use deprecated methods `find_element_by_*`. None of these is supported by Selenium 4.
Also code you shared is missing delays to wait for elements to become clickable etc.
The following short code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://shop.rtrpilates.com/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header__inline-menu a[href*='contact']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".contact__fields input[type='email']"))).send_keys("n@gmail.com")
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Thanks again
@Prophet hey it's working for that website , But it's not working for another website driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Contact') ??? driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]').click() I want to send email command based on clicking contact url link. If there is no contact link then email command will pass